# Would upgrading my Dell Optiplex 760 system four single 1GB sticks be better than just using one 4GB stick or even two 2GB sticks?

Tags: memory

I would like to speed up my elderly Dell Optiplex 760 which has four 1GB RAM sticks in place, but as it's 32-bit I understand that it won't accept more than 4GB. Actually only 3.6 usable.

So my query is: Might just two 2GB sticks operate in any way faster than four single 1GB's please? Or might just one 4GB stick be even better?

Comment: If your performance is caused by a lack of memory, switch to 2 GB modules, will have zero impact on your performance. You should consider just reinstalling your operating system to make it 64-bit. You should edit your question's title, we are unaware, of any previous query you might have had.

Comment: An SSD will speed it up, the mobo will take 8GB if you reinstall Win 64-bit. one 4GB stick will be slower than either 2x2 or 4x1… though neither would be worth the effort. You could buy a whole computer on eBay, 5 years newer & twice as fast, for $£€ 50.

Comment: I [edited your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1704090/revisions) to make it fit with this site but you used the sentence “Follow-up to prior query!” but I cannot see any prior query. To me, this says you posted a question before that was as casual in tone, like your original edit here, and a bit unclear. Please, this community is here to help you. But you need to be able to at least ask a question that fits with this site’s structure, tone and format. More info [here in the help center](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).